# Can I add participants to an existing event registration?

Tags: civievent

I've searched for answers on this but what I have found was either not quite on point or several years old, so I thought I'd check again.

I have an event set up where participants could register themselves plus additional participants. One registrant missed the option to add additional people and only registered herself, and wants my help registering her husband. But I can't see how to add participants manually on my end. "Change selections" doesn't allow me to change the quantity of registrations. (This was a credit card registration).

Is this a thing that can be done or not? Or am I looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to track that the husband was registered by the wife, you can just add the husband as a new participant through the interface at Events>Register Event Participant (though if it needs to be paid you will need to have one of them give you a credit card number over the phone). Or have one of them register the husband separately via the method that the wife used originally.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I ended up having her do: register the husband separately. It seemed the least complicated solution for both of us. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would add the Husband as a New Participant for the Event. Via API explorer or mysql set civicrm_participant.registered_by_id to wife participant ID.

Comment: I'm afraid that's beyond my technical knowledge. But thank you for the suggestion.